# Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin Problem - No band encountered

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, classification, scp

I am new to the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin. I am currently trying to produce Land Surface Temperature maps using satellite images (Landsat8) from Earth Explorer.

I have downloaded the B10, B11 TIF and the MTL.txt documents needed. The SCP plugin is also installed on my QGIS 3.28.11. I noticed that under "Preprocessing", the "Landsat" function is missing although it is available in all of the Youtube tutorial videos I have watched.

Has there been any updates that has changed the mechanism of producing LST images?

When I try proceeding with "Converting IMages" under "Preprocessing", a warning sign stating "Warning: No bound found. Check the metadata inside the directory" pops up.